# How i can find names of all available GIMP commands/tools.

Tags: gimp

I need to have a list of all available tools/commands name in GIMP(http://www.gimp.org/) for my research project.I have googled and also checked the source code but couldn't find any file that contains all name.

Can anyone suggest how can i get that list?

Answer (score 1):

[Gimp tools list](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tools.html)

[Gimp commands manual](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)